# How do you search an array of documents in mongo dart?

Tags: mongodb, dart

How do I search an array of documents in mongodb using the dart programming language?

Im using https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mongo_dart for the driver

The example db collection looks like this

`"name": [ 
     {"full":"Tyler Thompson",
      "first":"Tyler",
      "last":"Thompson"
     }
]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the following query will help achieve your goal for the one name

`String search = "Tyler";`

`{"name.full": {'\$regex': '${search}'}`

Hope that helps! Couldn't find an example, so I thought I'd give one!:)

Comment: If there is a better way of doing this then Im more then happy to accept that answer :) Still new to mongodb an Dart

Answer (score 2):

You can try to look at https://github.com/vadimtsushko/mongo_dart/blob/master/example/queries.dart

It is plausible that for your sample something like this would work:

```
coll.find(where.eq('name.full','Tyler'))
```

or maybe

```
coll.find(where.match('name.full','^Tyl[eo]r'))
```